# Getting Around Captchas

Tags: php, curl, captcha, recaptcha

I'm trying to (on the user's behalf) access and post to a website that, among other things, has an image captcha. Is there a way with cURL and PHP to get around that?

What I was thinking of was taking a screenshot, cropping it to only get captcha part, and letting my user tell me what the captcha is and then I'd submit it.

Is this a correct way to go about it? Any other (easier) ways to get around that?

Comment: The correct way is to respect the websites decision not to allow automatic commits. Ask the maker of the website if you can have access to an api/account that can post on the user's behalf, and if they refuse, then just don't.

Comment: @wrikken by still showing the captcha to the user he is not bypassing the captcha, he's just providing a different means to view it

Comment: @wrikken I'm not deleting the Captcha. I'm not posting automatically. I'm providing another interface, one for my user and my getting the Captcha and answering it correctly, simultaneously doing the goal of the Captcha.

Comment: The captcha may be there because the owner only wants you to use that interface. Seriously, ask first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use an HTML parser to find the URL of the CAPTCHA image, and show that URL to the user.

Comment: I, for one, would like to thank you for actually answering the question. I appreciate it. Gracias.

Comment: @Adam: Your question was somewhat vague; most people thought you were trying to _bypass_ the CAPTCHAs.

Answer (score 1):

If they are using a common library, such as google's recaptcha, it is unlikely that anything you try will work. They are designed to protect against exactly that. If they are using some hacked together library, then it's possible, but rather than trying to demonstrate a vulnerability, I'd simply advise them to use a well-known library.

Comment: he's not necessarily trying to get around the captcha, but just ask the user to answer the captcha to submit some generated form data.

Answer (score 0):

How about putting the other page with the captcha content in an IFrame on your page. Then use Javascript to keep on checking the URL of the IFrame to check whether the captcha went through or not, you can then proceed to doing whatever in your page. This of course assumes that the page with the captcha allows being put in an IFrame.